# Can an Execute Immediate statement be nested inside another Execute Immediate

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure  where is an Execute Immediate will call a "Begin ... End " block which contains another Execute Immediate  which will be called only if a certain condition is met.

The inner Execute Immediate command inside "Begin... End clock" is enclosed in single quotes. So it looks like

```
BEGIN
...SOME STUFF HERE...

FOR ..... LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
           'BEGIN
              IF (condition) THEN
                     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DML STRING'
              END IF
            END;'

END LOOP;

END;
```

That begs another question can an Execute Immediate statement be called from within the loop. I think the answer is yes.

Comment: Try it and let us know what happens!

Comment: I think in general it should work but you may have some trouble with quotes. I would suggest to review your design and avoid the nested strings.

Comment: Just because it bugs me (sorry): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can.

```
begin
    execute immediate
        'begin
             execute immediate ''begin dbms_output.put_line(''''Hello''''); end;'';
         end;';
end;
```

I think it's the road to hell, but yes, it is possible.

Comment: 1+ for road to hell.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show your real code, however I think such procedure could be re-written for example like this:

```
DECLARE
   res BOOLEAN
BEGIN
...SOME STUFF HERE...

FOR ..... LOOP
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN res := '||condition||'; END;' USING OUT res;
   IF res THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DML STRING';
   END IF;

END LOOP;

END;
```

Note, in earlier version `USING res` was possible only for native SQL data types, i.e. BOOLEAN or PL/SQL types were not possible. As far as I remember the feature was added in Oracle 12.1 but I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. I am on Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 unfortunately. so the basic question remains. Can an Execute Immediate be nested?

Comment: Then reshape the condition that it returns `1/0` rather than `TRUE/FALSE` and run the second command based on `IF res = 1 THEN ...`