# Oracle PL/SQL - Nested Open For inside Open For

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

For a more complicated situation I'm trying to `OPEN FOR` for text that includes a nested `OPEN FOR`, and I'm completely stumped:

Was hoping this would work:

```
DECLARE 
  cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  cur2 SYS_REFCURSOR;
  inner_text varchar2(1024) := 'select * from test_table';
  outer_text varchar2(1024) := 'open :1 for :2';
BEGIN
    open cur for outer_text using cur2, inner_text;
  -- dbms_sql.return_result(cur2);
END;
```

**== edit**

I have a proc that takes inline SQL and runs it against a bunch of parameters. Unfortunately that list of parameters has the potential to grow to 100+ so continuing on like I'm doing below isn't an option. I also need to swap out `OPEN FOR` for `EXEC IMMEDIATE` for `UPDATE/INSERTS` which is easier when I'm dynamically generating the SQL from the proc.

```
create or replace procedure exec_sql_text (
   sql_text       varchar2
  ,param_ar_text  varchar2 -- default '[]'

  ,cur out sys_refcursor
) as

  param_ar_text_default varchar2(16384) := case when param_ar_text is null then '[]' else param_ar_text end;

  param_json_ar json_array_t := json_array_t ( param_ar_text_default );
  len int := param_json_ar.get_size();

  type string_varray is varray(100) of varchar2(4096);
  ar string_varray := string_varray();

begin
  
  -- convert json_array_t to varray
  for i in 0 .. param_json_ar.get_size - 1 loop
    ar.extend; ar(i + 1) := param_json_ar.get_String(i);
  end loop;

  if    len = 0 then open cur for sql_text;
  elsif len = 1 then open cur for sql_text using ar(1);
  elsif len = 2 then open cur for sql_text using ar(1), ar(2);

  else  Raise_Application_Error( -20001, 'exec_sql_text: param-array length out of range, length: ' || len );
  end if;

end exec_sql_text;
```

It seems to be possible with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` so I assumed `OPEN CURSOR FOR` would be possible as well.

**== edit 3 per @William:**

The situation is that a massive sinking legacy app written with inline SQL needs to switch to procs to avoid sql injection and do things like authorize the session and handle errors.

The JSON structure is a simple array. I opted for JSON because I was trying to build the proc so it could accept any column-type of parameters and JSON would preserve the type. Unfortunately `OPEN FOR` wouldn't allow the json-type, however PL/SQL automatically handles the string-to-type conversion so it didn't really matter and I stuck with JSON.

Then I thought I might get lucky passing the entire array as 1 parameter to `OPEN FOR` then regex `:1 :2 :3` to `:1(1) :1(2) :1(3)` but `OPEN FOR` rejected that.

Not included in the proc is the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` but I'll include that part of the proc below. Based on a [different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728499/can-an-execute-immediate-statement-be-nested-inside-another-execute-immediate), I'm confident I could have built the string `execute immediate :1 using :2, :3` and run it from another `execute immediate`.

JSON Array to run the proc:

```
DECLARE 
  cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  sql_text varchar2(1024) := 'select * from users where name = :1 and state = :2';
  param_json_ar varchar2(1024) := '["Sean","MA"]';
BEGIN
  exec_sql_text(sql_text, param_json_ar, cur);
  dbms_sql.return_result(cur);
END;
```

Proc including `execute immediate`

```
create or replace procedure exec_sql_text (
   sql_text       varchar2
  ,param_ar_text  varchar2 -- default '[]'

  ,cur out sys_refcursor
) as

  param_ar_text_default varchar2(16384) := case when param_ar_text is null then '[]' else param_ar_text end;

  param_json_ar json_array_t := json_array_t ( param_ar_text_default );
  len int := param_json_ar.get_size();

  type string_varray is varray(100) of varchar2(4096); -- not null;
  ar string_varray := string_varray();

  is_update boolean := instr(sql_text, 'update') > 0;
  is_insert boolean := instr(sql_text, 'insert') > 0;
  is_delete boolean := instr(sql_text, 'delete') > 0;

begin
  for i in 0 .. param_json_ar.get_size - 1 loop
    ar.extend; ar(i + 1) := param_json_ar.get_String(i);
  end loop;

  if is_update or is_insert or is_delete then
    if    len = 0 then execute immediate sql_text;
    elsif len = 1 then execute immediate sql_text using ar(1);
    elsif len = 2 then execute immediate sql_text using ar(1), ar(2);
    elsif len = 3 then execute immediate sql_text using ar(1), ar(2), ar(3);
    else  Raise_Application_Error( -20001, 'exec_sql_text: param-array length out of range, length: ' || len );
    end if;
    open cur for 'select ''success'' as status from dual';

  else

    if    len = 0 then open cur for sql_text;
    elsif len = 1 then open cur for sql_text using ar(1);
    elsif len = 2 then open cur for sql_text using ar(1), ar(2);
    elsif len = 3 then open cur for sql_text using ar(1), ar(2), ar(3);
    else  Raise_Application_Error( -20001, 'exec_sql_text: param-array length out of range, length: ' || len );
    end if;

  end if;
end exec_sql_text;
```

Comment: That does not make sense.  what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? "open" is not a DML statement.

Comment: @OldProgrammer thanks for your help, I've added the actual proc

Comment: It's a bit difficult to reproduce your issue without knowing the json structure or the SQL being generated. There are techniques for handling variable parameter lists though, so perhaps if you could reduce your [mcve] to that I might be able to suggest something (or not). Out of interest, what is the `execute immediate` approach that is working where `open for` is not?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thanks for the feedback on this, I really appreciate the help. I've edited the post to hopefully better explain the situation. I included the example call. I'm not sure how to minimize the example any further because I don't know which part of it could be improved to solve the situation.